# R table with where condition

Tags: r, where-clause

I have a simple table (age by marital status) for individuals in a range of geographical zones.

I'd like to produce a table for each of these, would this be possible to do using a where statement, something along the lines of :

```
table(age, marital status)
where geo="Town A"
```

Comment: Post a sample of your data. The way to do this would be to `table` a subset of your data by using the `[` operator. e.g. `table( df[ df$geo == "Town A" , c("Age" , "marital_Status") ] )`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to post sample data in future.